# List search results as normal files (instead of hyperlinks)

Tags: windows-7, windows, search, windows-search

I have a very strange behavior on my Windows 7 x64 (upgraded from Vista).
When I perform a search from a folder, the search results are displayed as hyperlinks. This means they are underlined when I mouse-over them, and they open on single click.

This is very annoying because I cannot select several files/folders from the search results.

Folder options are correct, i.e. are set to "Double-click to open any item", I looked at them in the "Folder options" and in the "Folder and Search options" menus.

Other folders are displayed correctly, it's just the search results that show this behavior.
Also my colleagues Win7 x64 boxes do display results in the "correct" way.

How can I disable this option (provided there is one)?